# Postgresql/npgsql cant write when useing danish letters

Tags: c#, postgresql, unicode, utf-8, npgsql

I get this error when i try to write to my postgresql DB.

> NpgsqlException: ERROR: 22021: invalid byte sequence for encoding
>   "UTF8": 0xe5 0x27 0x2c

It only happen when i use danish letters (æ ø å).

Is there a way to set it to use ex. Unicode ?

I use Npgsql in a C# project.

I have no problem at all when iam not useing the danish letters.

Comment: Please show the code that generates that exception, the query, and the parameters passed. The PostgreSQL and nPgSQL versions would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(
         "Server="+ConnectionInfo +";"+
         "Port=5432;" +
         "User Id=MyAdmin;" +
         "Password=Test;" +
         "Database=MyDB;"+
         "Encoding = Unicode"
         );

     conn.Open();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your app is buggy. It's sending latin-1 encoded strings as if they were utf-8.

The byte sequence in the error is the *latin-1* for the string:

```
å',
```

per:

```
regress=> SELECT convert_from(BYTEA '\xe5272c', 'latin-1');
 convert_from 
--------------
 å',
(1 row)
```

You must either set `client_encoding` correctly to reflect the encoding of the text you're sending, or (preferably) use proper C# unicode strings when working with nPgSQL.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem when I do copy and paste from word document or notepad into my C# application textbox field. 
The simple solution is to add "Encoding = Unicode" into your postgresql connection string of your c# application. How simple could that be. I was relieved after going through three days of google search.